# Load DIVs with same class into a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm creating a fairly simple FAQ system to overhaul my company's outdated one. The page layout is very basic:

```
<div class="faq_c"> // Container
  <div class="faq_q">Question Goes Here</div>  // Question -- clicking this should open the Answer div in a dialog
  <div class="faq_a">Answer Goes Here</div> // Answer
</div>
```

The `faq_a` class has `display:none` set in CSS to hide it.

What I'm wanting to do is have each `faq_a` load into a modal dialog when the parent `faq_q` class DIV is clicked. The structure of the modal should be:

```
Question
--------- // Horizontal Rule formatted with CSS
Answer
```

**jQuery (Revised)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.faq_a').each(function(){
            $('.faq_a').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                overflow: scroll,
                title: "Frequently Asked Question",
                width: 500
            });

        $('.faq_q').click(function(){
            $('.faq_a').dialog('open');
        });
    });
});
```

This isn't working exactly correctly. Instead of opening the single desired `faq_a` it's opening all of them. I also can't figure out how to get the desired layout inside the div.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to [fix your selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbLLzv4p/1/)

```js
//var $dialog = $('<div>' + $('.faq_q') + '<hr>' + $('.faq_a') + '</div>'); // bad 

var $dialog = $('div, .faq_q, hr, .faq_a');// good 



$dialog.click(function() {
  alert('clicked');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
click me
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I integrated it into my original code. Now I'm getting an Uncaught Exception SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) on line 17 which is simply });

Comment: @rws907 did you check the semi colon after the var declaration?

Comment: @rws907 If you can set it up in a jsFiddle or stack snippet, I'll take another look.